# Reference counting in C and memory allocated inside function

Tags: c, function, gcc, return, malloc

I'm (attempting?) returning memory allocated inside a function.

Assuming there are no obvious problems with what I wrote here (and didn't test) how is the memory freed or not freed? I need to `free(bob)` later because he's on the heap not the stack, right?

I read something about reference counting in C in [another accepted answer just now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11752628/1048432) but I really really don't remember C having anything like a garbage collector.

```
char* strCat5000(char *fmt, ...)
{
  char buff[5000];
  char *ret_;
  va_list arg_ptr;
  va_start(arg_ptr, fmt);
  vsnprintf(buff, sizeof(buff), fmt, arg_ptr);
  va_end(arg_ptr);
  //ret_ = malloc((char*)(strlen(buff)+1)*sizeof(char)); //Allocated inside function
  ret_ = (char*)malloc((strlen(buff)+1)*sizeof(char)); //moved (char*) .. typo
  ret_ = strcpy(ret_,buff);
  return (ret_);
}
...
void findBob()
{
  char * bob;
  bob = strCat1000("Server is %s for %d seconds.", "on fire", 35329);
  printf("%s", bob);
  free(bob); //bob needs to be freed here or he'll leak when findBob ends???
}
```

Comment: reference counting has nothign to do with garbage collection. It is a pattern used to manage memory, but it's still manual from the programmers POV

Comment: You're right, C doesn't have a garbage collector. Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: @EdS.: Not necessarily. Python uses reference counting, and it's transparent to the programmer.

Comment: @icktoofay That's because Python is also doing the `malloc`s itself.

Comment: You need to free the bob. Nothing is automatic.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know if there's a problem. That's part of the problem. I might have a leak and I might be free-ing when I don't have to. (curse having to program in .NET for money... I've forgotten how to write a real program.)

Comment: @icktoofay: Likewise with CEF (Chromium Embeddable) and I believe also Mozilla Firefox, if I remember correctly. It can be done very transparently, maybe not with "pure" C but at least with C++.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, but it's still garbage collection.

Comment: Does this bit even compile "malloc((char*)(strlen(buff)+1)*sizeof(char));". Besides why write such incomprehensible code

Comment: I note that you're casting the argument to `malloc` to a `char *`. That's very strange; typically, you'd only cast the *return value*, and [then it's still somewhat discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845). Secondly, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, although feel free to be explicit I guess.

Comment: @EdHeal It shouldn't compile. I'll fix that. (char*) should have been outside.

Comment: @AppFzx - You do not even need it outside either

Comment: @AppFzx - And you do not need the `sizeof(char)` bit as well

Comment: @icktoofay: Python uses reference couting to *implement* a GC

Comment: Hacked the question a bit so we don't do a lot of manual `malloc/strcpy` when strdup exists (at least in POSIX).

Comment: @PerLundberg Better not to modify the question and remove parts which have discussion existing. I'm modifying your modification to preserve original as comments.

Comment: @PerLundberg nevermind.. someone already rejected it

Comment: @AppFzx: possibly. Just couldn't resist one chance of doing some nice refactorings. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You must "free Bob" in the findBob() method, since otherwise there will be no further notion of that particular piece of memory in your program => you will have a leak. So, in short: yes, that memory must be freed.

But then, just a side note: this kind of code is very "error prone". If you have a function allocating memory which the caller is supposed to free, it might be a good idea to have a `freeBob()` method or similar, which makes this purpose very obvious. It's usually a good idea to have `malloc()` and `free()` calls happen at the *same level of abstraction*. E.g. two functions in the same .c file might be a reasonable "abstraction level" in this case.

Comment: I quite completely disagree with the idea that free-ing inside a 3rd function to preserve *level of abstraction* makes code more readable or maintainable but... from hunting around the interwebs, that does look like what's proper.

Comment: Well, if you think of a public API (which this may or may not be), it feels more natural to have a `get_foo()` method which returns some form of data structure, and a `free_foo()` method coupled along with it to take care of the deallocation. Yes, it might feel like "meaningless extra code", but I think it's good. What if `get_foo` would allocate an object, which has an embedded extra-object which has to be deallocated also, for example? So, I actually think that this approach is quite good; it makes the code more robust in my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct, if you return heap-allocated data from a function, it needs to be freed eventually (unless you need it until the program is finished, then you can depend on the fact that all memory is freed when the process exits).

Reference counting is a technique used to avoid freeing memory too soon. If you may copy a pointer into a number of variables, you don't want to free it while any of them are still using it. You allocate a structure that contains a `refcount` member. Every time you assign the pointer to another variable, you must increment the refcount, as well as decrement the refcount of whatever that variable was pointing to previously. When the refcount drops to 0, you can call `free()`.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting)

Comment: "then you can depend on the fact that all memory is freed when the process exits". True, but this kind of coding is generally considered a bit sloppy I would say...

Comment: this part: "you may depend on the fact that all memory is freed when the process exits" gives me the creeps. Is that documented somewhere outside wikipedia to work cross platform with all (reputable) compilers?

Comment: @AppFzx: I don't think there would be an operating system in production use where this does not apply. Still, I agree 100%, it's bad practice to write code that works like that. It's much better to have an assertion that runs when the program exits to make sure that all (global) state has been properly deallocated, or something like that (and then of course also perform that deallocation. ;)

Comment: It's part of the definition of a process.

Answer (score 1):

To handle the above issue you have two approaches.

1st is what you are doing, that is `free` the bob after its use.Because nothing is `automatic` in c.

2nd is you can pass `parameter` to `strCat1000` in which you want to store the result(let say it as `store_var`). In that case `store_var` will be on stack (it must be declared inside the `findBob`) and it will be automatically deallocated after `findBob` ends.

If you want freedom from `free` then make your code free from `malloc`.

Something like this could work:

```
void findBob()
{
  char store_var[1000];
  strCat1000(store_var,"Server is %s for %d seconds.", "on fire", 35329);
  ...

void strCat1000(char to_save[],char *fmt, ...)
{
  ret_ = strcpy(to_save,buff); //check for lengths also.
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it real simple I wrote the following peace of code (c++). just run it and monitor your code memory usage using task manager.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
int * allocate(unsigned size)
{
    int * arr = new int[size];
    for(unsigned i=0;i<size;i++)
        arr[i] = i;
    return arr;
}
int main()
{
    int * p;

    p = allocate(1000000);
    getch(); // Here you still occupy the memory
    free(p); // here you free the memory you occupy in the function
    getch(); // here you should see that memory is freed before returning from the main
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks reasonable but I'm arbitrarily confining myself to C for this project because I decided I'm offended by C++'s numerous problems. In fact I'm migrating to http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-cilk-plus as soon as I have time to breath.